# Understanding Maven Repository in Server

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am new to Maven and trying to understand how it works. In eclipse when I run the pom.xml file, I see that it tries to look the settings.xml file from maven home and gets the repository url and pulls the dependencies and places it in local repository and it uses it. The end result of pom.xml is a jar file, it contains class files and pom.xml file inside META-INF folder.
Now placing this jar in server location, how does the server resolves the dependencies ? Server also does the same like searching for settings.xml and pulls the dependencies ? Or how the server executes the code which is inside dependent's jar?